# How to avoid apostrophe key (') working as double quotes (")

Tags: windows, windows-11

I always use the United States-International keyboard layout on Windows 11.

I don't know why, but from time to time when i hit apostrophe key ' (the key immediatelly on the left side from the Enter key), it will work as double quotes ".

First i thought it was because a change on the keyboard layout , but when i check on the language bar (right bottom of the screen), it's correctly set.

Then out of sudden, it get back to work correctly again.

Any cues about what could be causing this ?

Comment: Shift `'` should be `"`, but the International layout introduces dead-keys to add accents, é etc. If you don't need accents, don't use International.

Comment: @Tetsujin I need accents, that's why i use International

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple languages or keyboard layouts installed and are switching between them

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple keyboard layouts, you can change the layout by pressing the `Win`+`space` keys.

The layout can change automatically when you change focus to another application, since when you launch an application it will choose automatically the default layout based on the language.

You can still remap single keys by using Microsoft Power Toys (Keyboard Manager): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager

**To disable Automatic Keyboard Layout Switching**:

1. Open Settings (`Win`+`I`).
2. Time & language
3. Typing
4. Advanced Keyboard Settings
5. Let me use a different keyboard input for each app window.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this automatic change of layout ?

Comment: I updated the answer.